# For loop shows the wrong maximum value

Tags: python, for-loop

```py
a,b,c = int(input("Type value a ")), int(input("Type value b ")), int(input("Type value c "))
    
for num in a,b,c:
    if num >= b and num >= c:
        max_num = a
    elif num >= a and num >=c:
        max_num = b
    else:
        max_num = c
print(f'The max number is {max_num}')
```

The output doesn't add up. for example here's a sample output:

```
Type value a 100
Type value b 20
Type value c 10
The max number is 10
```

I would like to know the mistake I've made in how `num in a,b,c` is iterated.  To elaborate, in my mind, the for loop takes the first number (`num`) `a` and then compares it to `b` and `c`.  If it's less, then it moves on to the `elif` condition and lastly `c`.  This is repeated for `a,b,c`.

Explain how I've misunderstood how for loops or `if`/`elif` work if that's the issue.

Comment: You don't set `max_num` to `a` or `b` or `c` it should be setting it to `num` as thats the value you're looping over. also, the `max()` function in python can do this automatically.

Comment: Yes, please, just write: `max([int(input("Type value a" " ")),int(input("Type value b" " ")),int(input("Type value c" " "))])`. Everything more complicated is bad for the eyes...

Comment: Even better: `print(max([int(input(f"Type value {l}:")) for l in 'abc']))`

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please take the [tour] and read [ask] for tips like starting with your own research and how to write a clear question. For-loops simply don't work like that, so what makes you think they do? Maybe you read a bad tutorial? Have you tried reading other tutorials? For example you might try [the official one](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements), though if you're just starting programming, ignore the stuff about other languages.

Answer (score 4):

The logic you tried to implement with `if..elif` should not need a *loop*. Executing it once with the right value for `num`, would be enough:

```
if a >= b and a >= c:
    max_num = a
elif b >= a and b >= c:
    max_num = b
else:
    max_num = c
```

You can also solve it with a loop, but then you would incrementally improve a previous maximum. So you'd start with assuming `a` is the greatest, and then check if any of the two others are greater:

```
max_num = a
for num in b,c:
    if num >= max_num:
        max_num = num
```

Finally, Python has a function for this:

```
max_num = max(a, b, c)
```

Answer (score 1):

These might be some solutions for your problem:

```py
a,b,c = int(input("Type value a ")), int(input("Type value b ")), int(input("Type value c "))
max_num = -1
for num in a,b,c:
    if max_num < num:
        max_num = num
print(f'The max number is {max_num}')
```

or simply

```py
a,b,c = int(input("Type value a ")), int(input("Type value b ")), int(input("Type value c "))
print(f'The max number is {max(a,b,c)}')
```

Now for the explanation of your mistake, First there is no involvement of `max_num` inside your loop other than assignment. For each iteration your checking if the element is a or b or c (although not perfectly) and assigning them to `max_num` so in the end the `max_num` contains the value of `c`

Comment: The first option fails if `a, b, c` are all less than `-1`. You could use `float('-inf')` as your default minimum instead, or simply use `a`.

Comment: Er, it doesn't fail, it produces the wrong result: `-1`.

Answer (score 1):

This is why I am a proponent of learning a moderately low-level language as your first language. The shortcuttery offered by python often distorts program logic. This would be a typical correct implementation:

```
a = int(input("Type value a: "))
b = int(input("Type value b: "))
c = int(input("Type value c: "))

max_num = a # not 0

arr = [a, b, c]

print(arr)

for num in arr:
    if max_num < num:
        max_num = num

print (f'The max number is {max_num}')
```

You had to:

- Give a value first (initizalize) to max number. Because otherwise, what would it compare itself to?
- num in this for loop would be iterating through value inside the array which are a, b and c respectively.
- max_num would be compared to said value, and if the value if greater, would be assigned as the new max number.

I do not know any python syntax `for num in a,b,c` but my way highlights the logic clearly. We first *solve* the problem, *then* we proceed to optimize and shortcut or what have you.

Hope this helps.

Update: As @trincot has pointed out, if we wish to compare max_value out of a, b and c, we initialize max_value to a, not 0.

Answer (score -1):

```
a,b,c = int(input("Type value a" " ")),int(input("Type value b" " ")),int(input("Type value c" " "))
    
for num in a,b,c:
    if num >= b and num >= c:
        max_num = a
    elif (num >= a) and (num >=c) :
        max_num = b
    else:
        max_num = c
    break # use break to correct the code
print (f'The max number is {max_num}')
```

your answer is now correct. Use 'Break' to stop the programme.

Comment: An unconditional `break` is almost always wrong. In this case, there's no point in looping; you might as well set `num = a` and leave it at that. But as others have answered, there are better ways to solve this problem.

Comment: @wjandrea how do you evaluate the quality of code, I understand that it should be concise and readable, but in a case such as this, what is the difference in terms of quality of code when using a for loop with an initialized variable ( max_num=a) and using a break statement such as in the answer above?

Comment: @Ess The problem with this code is that it does things it doesn't need to: looping, comparing `num >= a` (which will always be true since `num = a`), and setting up `for num in ... b,c` (which will never execute). It's deeper than just concision or readability: its actual *functionality* is bad. That said, it does produce the correct result, but in an illogical way. It's sort of like using a screwdriver to drive a nail when you could use a hammer or screws instead.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).